# What is the best way to scan for a keyword in the URL?

Tags: seo

What is the best way to scan for a keyword in the URL? Eg. I want to find the words "shirt" in the URL.

Comment: Programmaticly or a Jedi mind trick for your eyes?

Comment: I would normally migrate this to stackoverfow but they would immediately cose this as low quality. If you would like them to answer this for you, you will need to provide a lot more information about what language(s) you can use and what you've tried so far.